# C# XML documentation of Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, documentation, dbml

How to document the classes & properties & functions that are generated automatically using LINQ to SQL DBML?

I managed to provide documentation to the datacontext class by defining the same partial class in another file with `<summary>` so it won't be removed if the DBML got refreshed

```
/// <summary>  
/// Linq to SQL datacontext  
/// </summary>  
public partial class LinqDBDataContext {  

}
```

This would work for table mapping class with one downside is having to manually maintain the separate class for added/removed tables.

another thing..I have comments-like-documentation(author, date and description) in the stored procedure, shouldn't be also extracted into the code file as the function's documentation?

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Katia Aleid>
-- Create date: <2015-04-01>
-- Description: <Performs search for the users>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchUsers] ....
```

is it acceptable to exclude the DBML form C# documentation and have separate database documentation instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments *inside* a stored procedure are unlikely to be parseable by SqlMetal; *at a push*, it could  access the `MS_Description` extended metadata, if you've assigned some - however, I would not *expect* it to do that. Looking inside the dbml metadata, there isn't anywhere obvious to store or edit additional comments, so frankly I suspect the answer here is: you don't. You shouldn't edit the `*.designer.cs`, because that can be regenerated at random.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't mean that the comment were inside the procedure but before it. just like the template provided by SQL server when you request a new procedure. and as for the designer, I know I shouldn't edit it, that's why I add another file to extent the partial class.

Comment: @katia those comments are not obtainable by inspection - they are for the benefit of the file, not the SQL Server. Comments *inside* the stored procedure may be available via `sp_helptext` etc, but that doesn't make them consumable